# Want to write a confusion matrix in latex

Tags: matrices

I have a program from which i get the following:
- True Positives (TP).
- False Positives (FP).
- True Negatives (TN).
- False Negatives (FN).

I want to write a code in Tex that generates me the confusion matrix that will show me these four values in addition to other metrics like: Precision, Recall, Accuracy.

I would really appreciate your help, thanks in advance.

I want something like this:
[image: Confusion Matrix]

This is a sample code that I have just tried (but it gives me errors):

```
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{ccclclc}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}}  & \multicolumn{4}{c} 
{Correlation Results}  & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}Total Population}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Condition Positive (Malicious)} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Condition Negative (Non-Malicious)} & \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}Accuracy} \\
                                            & Test Outcome Positive (Anomalous) & \multicolumn{2}{c}{True Positive} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{False Positive} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{False Discovery Rate} \\
\multirow{-2}{*}{Anomaly Detection Results} & Test Outcome Negative (Non-Anomalous) & \multicolumn{2}{c}{False Negative} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{True Negative} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Negative Predictive Value} \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}sgdjd}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Recall}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{False Positive Rate (Fall-out)} & 
\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}F1 Score                  
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Can you put your full LaTeX code, please?

Comment: I think you need to give more clues on what the data and required output look like

Comment: For now I do not have Tex any code that does what I want. This is a template of what I want at the end: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity

Comment: I think you need to show (just as a text table) a full sample input for tex (ie a small sample output of your program) and an image showing the required typeset result for that input to tex  (just  fake output you can make in a drawing program)

Comment: I frankly do not know how to do this in latex, but I have updated my post with an example image of what I want.

Comment: But you could post what you have tried. Then others would not have to punch in the text from your screen shot. If you, for instance, provide a table without the colors, and ask how to add the colors, I am sure you will get a useful answer very quickly.

Comment: I just added a sample code in my post that I have just found and tried but no success

Comment: I do not get any error when I use the preamble `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}`. but of course the result is not even remotely similar to your screen shot, also because the only color you use is white.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. At the moment we have to guess what you are doing because we cannot compile your code from what you have posted.

Comment: Using the colortbl package, the only remaining problem is that \color[HTML]{FFFFFF} is apparently white.   That and the odd sgdjd.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this was translated from some other format (HTML?) by computer, so it works but in a round about manner.  Also, it seems to expect a color background, as in

[image: demo]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\colorbox{yellow}{%
\begin{tabular}{ccclclc}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}}  & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Correlation Results}  & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}Total Population}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Condition Positive (Malicious)} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Condition Negative (Non-Malicious)} & \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}Accuracy} \\
\multirow{2}{*}{Anomaly Detection Results} & Test Outcome Positive (Anomalous) & \multicolumn{2}{c}{True Positive} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{False Positive} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{False Discovery Rate} \\
                                            & Test Outcome Negative (Non-Anomalous) & \multicolumn{2}{c}{False Negative} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{True Negative} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Negative Predictive Value} \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}sgdjd}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Recall}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{False Positive Rate (Fall-out)} & 
\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}F1 Score                  
\end{tabular}}
\end{document}
```

Needless to say, this could be simplified and use a more intuitive color palette.